# Displaying an Image in ModelForm

Tags: django, modelform

I have the following model:

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='portraits/', default='/images/some_image.png')
```

For that I made the ModelForm:

```
 class PortfolioForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
        exclude = ['id']
```

I need many of those in one template so I am creating them in the Following way in my view

```
  def portfolio_form(request, pk):
       ...
       formset =  PortfolioFormSet(queryset=Portfolio.objects.filter(pk__in=list_of_ids))
```

for x in p]

finally in the html I have this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'elec:portfolio_form' pk=id %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  ...
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% for form in formset.forms %}
       <tr>{% for field in form %}
            {% if field.name == 'image' %}
                 <td><img src="{{field.image.url}}"></td>
            {% else %}
                 <td align="center" valign="middle">{{field}}</td>
            {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}</tr>
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save and Refresh" />
</form>
```

Now what I expect to see is the image that I am saving into that Model. The if statement is coming back as false but why?. What am I doing wrong? Everywhere I looked it should work like this.

Also I have added the request.FILES in PortfolioForm with that the instance is not called how can I fix that?

Comment: I can't understand why you would think `if field.image` would work. What makes you think the fields have an `image` attribute? Do you perhaps mean `if field.name == 'image'`?

Comment: Also, if you have multiple forms you should certainly not be creating them in a list comprehension like that, you should use a formset.

Comment: The image is still not showing, please help. I have corrected the code in the question!

Comment: Please can Daniel can you take another look and help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the solution in Stackoverflow since I used some other words to find a solution.

what you need to do in the template instead of :

```
{<td><img src="{{field.image.url}}"></td>}
```

is this :

```
{<td><img src="{{form.instance.image.url}}"></td>}
```